# putting X on an element to remove an element from <ul> list

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, user-interface

Currently, this is what i have

[image]

At the moment, the element can be dragged and dropped (at the moment, there is no listener to capture if it's dropped into a specified area)

**HTML**

```
<div class='left'>
<ul id="sortable">
    <li class="ui-state-highlight"></li>
    <li class="ui-state-highlight"></li>
    <li class="ui-state-highlight"></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#sortable" ).sortable({
          items: "li:not(.ui-state-highlight)",
          placeholder: "ui-state-highlight"
        });
        $( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
    });
  </script>
```

Ideally, I would like to have this.

[image]

A) Can someone point me to the right direction as to how to put an X at the end of the element so that the user can click on the X to remove it from the list.

B) Or, show me how to drag an unwanted element and drop it outside the list area to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to do some styling yourself. But here's an example:

```
# Example HTML
<div class='left'>
<ul id="sortable">
    <li class="ui-state-highlight" id="num1"><span></span></li>
    <li class="ui-state-highlight" id="num2"><span></span></li>
    <li class="ui-state-highlight" id="num3"><span></span></li>
</ul>
</div>

#Example CSS (you will have to do some styling yourself. You could for example use an image for the x or something)
#sortable .ui-state-highlight span {
    position: absolute;
    left: 2px;
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    background-color: white;
}

# Untested, but this should be corret (tho, untested)
$('#sortable').on('click','.ui-state-highlight span',function () {
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```